# Fullcalendar Not Displaying Events MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I have made a test page using the latest fullcalendar on a test page but it won't display the events in the calendar, any ideas?

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Cal</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.9.0/main.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.9.0/main.min.css">
    <script>

        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
            var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
            var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
                initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
                events: 'CalEvents/'
            });
            calendar.render();
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='calendar'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the controller code:

```
public ActionResult Cal()
{
   return View();
}

public JsonResult CalEvents()
{
   using (_context)
   {
       var events = _context.CalendarEventsNews.ToList();
       return Json(events.ToArray(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

   }
}
```

This is the response:

```
[{"id":1,"eventName":"Test","eventDescription":"Testing Description","eventLocation":"UK","startDate":"\/Date(1633561200000)\/","endDate":"\/Date(1633730400000)\/","allDay":false}]
```

Comment: Your `action` is an ajax action but where is the ajax call on the UI? You need to call the action, get the data and then render on the UI.

Comment: I have tried that and still get the same date output:
End: "/Date(1633561200000)/"
EventID: 1
IsFullDay: false
Start: "/Date(1633474800000)/"

Comment: Mainly the issue is that your event data doesn't match what fullCalendar expects. Did it occur to you to check the requirements? https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-parsing lists the valid field names. Whilst all the properties are _technically_ optional, realistically if you don't include, at minimum, a "title" and a "start" property (making sure the start date complies with the recognised date formats listed in the linked documentation) then it definitely won't be able to show your event...if it doesn't know where on the calendar to put the event then that's a pretty fundamental issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As ADyson had pointed out the issue was me simply not going through the documentation correctly. Field names changed and working fine now.

Thanks again ADyson for pointing out the issue.